# Selenium - record clicks on SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, svg

I need to record some tests for Selenium.

The tests contains some clicks over some elements. At double click an options circle appear. From there you can select create a new element, delete one, edit, etc.

[image]

All the elements are svg elements, and are manipulated with JavaScript. The problem is that I get "locator detection failed" error on that clicks.

What I need is to make an automated test like: add an element, edit it, delete it. If you need the SVG I'll post it... but nothing special there. Just some rectangles and text.

Also as a note: elements are redrawn after each add/delete/edit.